# "Detecting" an expired session with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, session

I am using the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/) package for my session and state management in ASP.NET Core.

Is there any way I can  "detect"  an expired session and automatically redirect to another view when it expires?
I can't really find anything about this particular usecase in the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the expiration time of the session first, and then write a timer to force redirection to a certain page when the session expires.

Below is my test code, you can refer to it.

I set the session expiration time to 10 seconds in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddSession(option =>
{
    option.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});
```

There is an action `Time` in my controller to get the expiration time of the session, and another page that needs to be redirected:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //get the expiration time of session
    public int Time()
    {
        var value = GetInstanceField(typeof(DistributedSession), HttpContext.Session, "_idleTimeout").ToString();
        string[] time = value.Split(':');
        var seconds = int.Parse(time[0])*60+ int.Parse(time[1]) * 60 + int.Parse(time[2]);
        return seconds;
    }
    private object GetInstanceField(Type type, ISession session, string v)
    {
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(v, bindFlags);
        return field.GetValue(session);
    }
    //the page to redirect
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then request `"/Home/Time"` and set the timer in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<script>
    var value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/Time",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            value = response;
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
    const sessionTime = function() {
        value = value - 1;

        if (value <= 0){
            window.location.href = "/Home/Test";
        }
    };
    setInterval(sessionTime, 1000);
</script>
```

When the program runs for 10 seconds, it will automatically redirect to the `/Home/Test` page:
[image]